# Ln command error "target not a directory"

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm, specifications, ln

I have the following code inside a spec file:

```
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_qt6_bindir}
pushd %{buildroot}%{_qt6_bindir}
for i in * ; do
  case "${i}" in
    qdbuscpp2xml|qdbusxml2cpp|qtpaths)
      ln -v  ${i} %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/${i}-qt6
      ;;
    *)
      ln -v  ${i} %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/${i}
      ;;
  esac
done
popd
```

when i run build i got following error:

```
ln: target '/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/qt6-qtbase-6.4.3-1.x86_64/usr/bin/qtpaths6': Not a directory
```

where qtpath6 is an excutable file.
how to fix this error?

Comment: Does the file already exist and you want to override it? Use `-f` flag. Are you positive that you want hard links rather than symbolic links?

Comment: yes the file already exists! and yes i want hard link and i tried -f also same error..

Comment: How about just including `rm -f %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/${i}-qt6` before the `ln -v ...` line?

Comment: tried but same error!

Comment: Which RH/CentOS version are you using? I haven't worked with rpmbuild for a while, but checked some old .spec files and they all do `rm -rf %{buildroot}` instead of trying to overwrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on is that a component of the target path is not a directory. I can reproduce the problem like this:

```
$ ln /etc/hosts/foo bar
ln: failed to access '/etc/hosts/foo': Not a directory
```

That's because `/etc/hosts` is a file.  I picked that well-known file to make it obvious.

(The wording of the diagnostic is not exactly the same in my version of `ln` as you can see.)

What's probably happening is that `ln` calls the `link` system call, which fails with a -1 and an `errno` of `ENOTDIR`. The program just translates that error to `Not a directory` via `strerror`, and attributes the error to the target path as such.

We know that `ln` cannot possibly be complaining that the target isn't a directory, because that is specifically **disallowed**: you cannot make a hard link to a directory!

```
$ ln /etc ./etc
ln: /etc: hard link not allowed for directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is simply: "Spec files are not any form of scripting language", as answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/894771/can-i-run-for-loop-over-files-directive-in-the-spec-file).